# AspNet Core Scoped Dependency Interface Segregation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, structuremap

So,

```
// this doesn't work or make sense
services.AddScoped<IReadSomething>(sp => new Something());
services.AddScoped<IWriteSomething>(sp => new Something());
```

So I have two Interfaces for the same Class, `IReadSomething` and `IWriteSomething`, the Class is just `Something`.

They need to be scoped because they transfer a subset of data from `HttpContext` to a arbitrary framework independent 'DTO'.

They both should be referencing the same Instance of `Something`, obviously one just exposes some read and the other, some write operations. So it gets written somewhere in the Middleware pipeline - and the rest of the app can just use the `IReadSomething` and read data so we can mitigate accidental data overwrite.

Doing,

```
services.AddScoped<IReadSomething, Something>();
services.AddScoped<IWriteSomething, Something>();
```

Doesn't make sense either because, quite rightly, it should create a new instance for each interface.

What am I missing to get Interface Segregation and Scoped Dependency Resolution to work together - I feel like I have to worry about the ASP.NET Core Scoped Service Factory or something?

I'm also using structuremap for my main dependency resolution - so an answer using that is fine.

Comment: I've got the answer for structuremap, `.Forward<TFrom, TTo>()` what about AspNet Core

Comment: @Nkosi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52278757/2630078) has you covered for the ASP.NET Core DI Container - You could easily take his answer and generate your own extension method that emulates that StructureMap function too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make the target class scoped and then associate it with the desired interfaces

```
services.AddScoped<Something>();
services.AddScoped<IReadSomething>(sp => sp.GetService<Something>());
services.AddScoped<IWriteSomething>(sp => sp.GetService<Something>());
```

That way a call for either interface will return the same instance in scope